# How can i add link when user press on image?

Tags: flutter

i have this code lines:

```
children: <Widget> [
        Image(image: AssetImage('assets/images/myimage.jpg')),
        SizedBox(height: 195),
        Text(
          'texthere',
        )]
```

I see the image but i don't find solution to add link when press on the image...
Can someone help me please?

thank you.

Comment: what do you mean by add link?

Comment: open link like href tag in html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `url_launcher`:
https://pub.dev/packages/url_launcher

## Step by step

1) Add `url_launcher` in latest version to you `pubspec.yaml`

2) Wrap your `Image()` or whole parent object e.g. `Column()` with `GestureDetector()` to recognize click. For example:

```
child: GestureDetector(
  child: Column(children: <Widget>[
    Image(
      image: AssetImage('assets/images/myimage.jpg'),
    ),
    SizedBox(
      height: 195,
    ),
    Text('texthere')
  ]),
  onTap: () {
    openUrl();
  },
),
```

3) Add `onTap`, and call here new method:

```
void openUrl() async {
  String url = "https://stackoverflow.com/";

  if (await canLaunch(url)) {
    await launch(url);
  }
}
```

Remember that this method is `async` and imports are from:

```
import 'package:url_launcher/url_launcher.dart';
```

Comment: hi i didn't success to put it maybe...  this part of the code that important: children: <Widget>[ Image.asset("assets/banner/imageneed.jpg",fit: BoxFit.fitWidth,height:MediaQuery.of(context).size.width/6.14),
            Container(

Comment: `I didn't success` - what it means? It does not work? Have you got any problem with import or what? Did you wrap your `Image` or `Column` within `GestureDetector` and add `onTap` parameter?

Comment: after littile changes yes thank you! hope you will help me in my other things your amazing!